# Toast on Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-toast

I have a receiver that is called when a sms is sent. 
When this happen, I want to show a toast. I know it is not a good practice to show a toast from a receiver, but I would like to know why my code does not work

```
public class SmsSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
      Toast.makeText(context, R.string.sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
      Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_sending_sms, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    context.unregisterReceiver(this);
  }

}
```

The receiver receives the event correctly but it does not show none of the toasts.
Instead, if I run the app in debug mode, one of the toasts appear correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you know it is called ?

Comment: Because I have put a breakpoint :)

Comment: If you are using context then it will show only to the activity. But broadcast receiver may be used in multiple activities.

Comment: @Shriram ok but even using context.getApplicationContext() it does not work

Comment: Try getBaseContext() instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Shriram It does not know that function... neither from the receiver nor using context.getBaseContext()

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         Toast.makeText(context, R.string.sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe your 'Show Notifications' setting is checked off in your app's settings?

Comment: No, I am sure. Even because the toasts are showed up when the app is running in debug mode :(

Comment: In that case, create a dummy activity that will show a toast and then finish immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
  public class SmsSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_sending_sms, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    context.unregisterReceiver(this);
  }

}
```

Hope this may help you...

Comment: Try getBaseContext() instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: It does not know that function... neither from the receiver nor using context.getBaseContext()

Comment: No need to use context.getBaseContext() just use getBaseContext() or getApplicationContext(),if it works...

Comment: BroadcastReceiver does not have those functions. I gotta use context to call getApplicationContext() and it does not have getBaseContext()

Comment: Like this :- Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.sent,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Try to create a class on the fly, extending BroadcastReceiver. You will see that getBaseContext() does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Context c;
...
...
....

Toast.makeText(c,"Succesfully Written",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```